# Zend framework : Print message and then redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using Zend framework version 1.11, trying to print message and then redirect to specific page

```
echo "Great day";
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Refresh',
                                       '3;URL=http://localhost/index.php');
```

I referred the link 
[Zend HeadMeta Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-meta.html)

However it gives the following error message

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Controller_Action_Exception'
 with message 'Method "headMeta" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()'
```

Can you please help to resolve the issue or suggest some other method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you have written this code in the controller, but headMeta () is a view helper, so try this:

```
$this->view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Refresh','3;URL=http://localhost/index.php');
```

Do not forget to add this in your layout:

```
echo $this->headMeta();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this via simple JavaScript.

```
echo <<<EOT

Good day.
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost/index.php';
    }, 2000/* set time here */);
</script>
EOT;
```

The while trying to redirect from server side we should not write anything before headers and also after some data is already written from server side and headers will also be sent. So, server side code will throw error.